# Automatic grant runtime permission in debug mode

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-debug, runtime-permissions

Is there any way to automatic grant runtime permission if I am in debug mode?

Because if I clear data I must grant all permission again.
And it's borring in debug.

Thank you.

Comment: No, there is no way

Comment: Have a look at this tutorial: http://buff.ly/1O55mGM - it's done by adding a task to your build.gradle file.

Comment: AFAIK, there no way you can do that.

Comment: @NongthonbamTonthoi see my comment - it is actually possible.

Comment: @Darwind I will check it

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 7):

With [adb](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html#pm), you can use the following command to grant the permissions when you install the app:

```
$ adb install -g <package>
```

With `-g` defined as follows:

> -g: Grant all permissions listed in the app manifest.